# How can I detect the scrolling height and to change title accordingly with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, html-lists

I would like to create a list with shops in different countries for my website. And I would like to know how can I know the scrolling has reached my desired area such that I can change the text in top title.

So my thought is that:
I should add class to li to indicate the last element for each region ("uk-last" & "us-last" & "jp-last")
So the default title will be displaying "UK". When the scrolling has reached "uk-last", it will replace the title text to US and do the same to JP.

I am wondering whether it is correct to detect the last element or actually i should detect the first element of each region instead.

I am not good at jQuery/js so I am quite confused about what I am going to do. Would you please give me some comments if you have any hints/solution.

Thank you so much!!!

```css
.title {
  background: yellow;
  color: red;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

ul li {
  margin: 10px;
  background: #f4f4f4;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.scroll {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="title">UK</p>
</div>
<div class="scroll">
  <ul>
    <li>UK Store 1<br>XXXXX<br>XXXXX<br>XXXXX<br>XXXXX</li>
    <li>UK Store 2<br>XXXXX<br>XXXXX<br>XXXXX<br>XXXXX</li>
    <li class="uk-last">UK Store 3<br>XXXXX<br>XXXXX<br>XXXXX<br>XXXXX</li>
    <li>US Store 1<br>XXXXX<br>XXXXX<br>XXXXX<br>XXXXX</li>
    <li>US Store 2<br>XXXXX<br>XXXXX<br>XXXXX<br>XXXXX</li>
    <li class="us-last">US Store 3<br>XXXXX<br>XXXXX<br>XXXXX<br>XXXXX</li>
    <li>JP Store 1<br>XXXXX<br>XXXXX<br>XXXXX<br>XXXXX</li>
    <li>JP Store 2<br>XXXXX<br>XXXXX<br>XXXXX<br>XXXXX</li>
    <li>JP Store 3<br>XXXXX<br>XXXXX<br>XXXXX<br>XXXXX</li>
    <li>JP Store 4<br>XXXXX<br>XXXXX<br>XXXXX<br>XXXXX</li>
    <li class="jp-last">JP Store 5<br>XXXXX<br>XXXXX<br>XXXXX<br>XXXXX</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) { 
        //change uk to us
        $('.title').html('US');
    } 
});
```